# Need help to find output from a parent child combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Sample records:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Child VARCHAR(5),
    Parent VARCHAR(5),
    Comment VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT @Temp VALUES
(1, 'C1', 'P1', 'AA'),
(1, 'C2', 'P2', ''  ),
(1, 'C3', 'P3', 'XX'),
(1, 'C4', 'P4', 'YY'),
(1, 'C5', 'P5', ''  ),
(1, 'C6', 'P6', 'ZZ'),
(1, 'C7', 'P7', ''  ),
(1, 'C8', 'P8', ''  ),
(1, 'C9', 'P9', 'TT'),
(1, 'C10','P10','')
```

The records of source table will look like records of the above @temp table.
Can we design a TSQL script which can use @temp as a source table and that script can give the output like the below result table.

IF the comment value is NULL/empty for a parent child combination, then the next succeeding NOT NULL/non empty comment need to replace.

---

The Output what I need is like this

```
ID  Child   Parent  [Comment]
1   C1      P1      AA 
1   C2      P3      XX  
1   C3      P3      XX  
1   C4      P4      YY  
1   C5      P6      ZZ  
1   C6      P6      ZZ  
1   C7      P9      TT  
1   C8      P9      TT  
1   C9      P9      TT  
1   C10     P10
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: I read this twice and have no idea what you're asking.  If you take some time to clarify what you have tried, what you expect, and what you need - people will be more willing to take some time to help you.

Comment: Need TSQL script which can use @temp as  a source table and that script can give the output like : the output of 2nd script

Comment: You mean, if the value for comment is empty, then succeeding non-empty value need to replace?

Comment: You are correct @Arulkumar

Comment: If you're only writing to a temp table so that you can select output from it, you don't need the temp table; you can just select your output from the REAL source (that you're currently using to populate your temp table).

Comment: going to be difficult to give you a perfect answer with the sample data you've given because some type of order needs to be determined...

Comment: @StanShaw, Man still you are not getting the question.It's not simple as you click the down vote option.

Comment: @aks Yep, I'm just too stupid to understand your well-articulated and clearly-presented, brilliant question.

Comment: You seem to have posted several questions of the form "got this, want that, please help." It would really help if you would take a deep breath, then read [Writing The Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). You'll get better answers faster if we can understand what you need the first time around. If you do need to clarify a question after posting it, please _edit the question_.

Comment: @HABO, thanks man I have edited and added more info to the question.Hope it will help a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of recursive cte:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT ID, Child, Parent, Comment
FROM @Temp
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, t.Child, c.Parent, c.Comment
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN @Temp t 
    ON CAST(STUFF(c.Child,1,1,'') as int) = CAST(STUFF(t.Child,1,1,'') as int)+1
WHERE t.comment = ''
)

SELECT  MAX(ID) as ID,
        Child,
        MAX(Parent) as Parent,
        MAX(Comment) as Comment
FROM cte
GROUP BY Child
ORDER BY CAST(STUFF(Child,1,1,'') as int)
```

Output:

```
ID          Child Parent Comment
----------- ----- ------ -------
1           C1    P1     AA
1           C2    P3     XX
1           C3    P3     XX
1           C4    P4     YY
1           C5    P6     ZZ
1           C6    P6     ZZ
1           C7    P9     TT
1           C8    P9     TT
1           C9    P9     TT
1           C10   P10    

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do what you want using OUTER APPLY to get the next valid ParentID and it's Comment.

```
SELECT  ID,
        Child,
        CASE WHEN t1.Comment = '' THEN NextParent ELSE Parent END AS Parent,
        CASE WHEN t1.Comment = '' THEN NextComment ELSE Comment END AS Comment
FROM @Temp t1 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Parent [NextParent], t2.Comment [NextComment]
             FROM @Temp t2 
             WHERE t2.Parent > t1.Parent AND t2.Comment <> ''
             ORDER BY t2.Parent) ca
```

the last value P10 will be incorrect because you have to manipulate those types of values to order them properly since P10 comes between P1 and P2